# Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks

Tags: angular

iam using this module:  `https://www.npmjs.com/package/correlation-id` , but when I run `ng serve`, am getting below error, may I know how to resolve it? BTW, am using amgular cli version is 9.1.0

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks'
```

Comment: This looks like a node module..? Not suitable to run in a browser.

Comment: @MikeOne  yes, this issue related to node_module, please add above module in package.json and then try npm install and ng serve, then you will see above error

Comment: Point is, this npm package might not be suitable for a browser - so might only run in a node environment. Angular runs in a browser..

Comment: @MikeOne can you pls suggest me which package is suitable for browser. how about uuid package? or any other similar better package?

Comment: Uuid is actually included in Angular